# Passing a global array to a function overwrites array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a global defined array as an argument to a function.
I thougt this function would treat the argument as a local variable.
But it doesn't... Changing the (in my opinion) local variable also changes the values of the global array. What am I doing wrong?

```
clickX = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    clickX[i] = i;
}
doThis(clickX);

function doThis(x) {
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        x[i]++;
        alert(clickX[i]); // this alerts the changed value of x[i] and not the origin value of the global array
    }
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/n546rq89/

Comment: Objects are passed by reference in JS. (`var x = [1,2,3]; var y = x; y.splice(0, 1); console.log(y); //[2, 3]`)

Comment: You're not changing the variable (which is indeed local, as you can confirm by `x = []`), you're changing the object (by modifying the properties of it).

Comment: Thanks, not it's getting clearer. How can I change values of the object in the function without changing the origin object? Somehow duplicate it?

Comment: See my answer for how to pass by value.

Comment: @Henning: yes, you have to create a new object that you then pass.

Comment: Understood and fixed my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: My opinion to the duplicate answer: The solution is the same, but I wouldn't have found it because I thougt my problem would be associated with the circumstance off the function and the argument. Same solution, but different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, arrays are passed by reference by default. You can alternatively pass `ARRAY.slice()` to pass by value:

```
clickX = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    clickX[i] = i;
}
doThis(clickX.slice());

function doThis(x) {
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        x[i]++;
        alert(clickX[i]); // this alerts the changed value of x[i] and not the origin value of the global array
    }
}
```

Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486130/5020253) for an explanation of `slice()` and copying array in JS.